# When is a string pool recycled in C#?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, string-pool

I know that string pools are associated with processes. And it will be recycled when the owner process exits or an application domain is unloaded.

But I wonder if an application is long running, will the string pool leak memory?

Comment: Only if you abuse `String.Intern()`. The [notes about performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#performance-considerations) tell you all you need to know.

Comment: The short answer is no. No general-use programming construct will unless it has a bug or was designed by complete morons.  (Or unless you're using it wrong, which takes some work in a GC language.

Comment: @spender Even if someone don't use `String.Intern()` and simply write `string A="Z"; string B="Z";` still there are only one object in string pool with value "Z" and hence it seems that it still only released when CLR terminates.

Comment: In addition it seems that to prevent interning using CompilationRelaxationsAttribute is vital. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilationrelaxationsattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2